# Do I really have to break encapsulation when defining out of line friend for a nested class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider such example:

```
class A
{
    class B {
        friend void f1(const B&){};
        friend void f2(const B&);
    };
    // friend void f2(const B&); // has to be repeated =[
};

void f2(const A::B&){}
```

**Is there a way to avoid friend repetition other than defining the function inline?**

I find it surprising that to pull definition out of a class it's needed to repeat oneself, leak details of nested class to the outer one, and IMHO most importantly allow access to `A` privates to the unrelated function.

The general rule of friendess is that it's not transitive, but here I am basically forced to break it for out-of-line definition, I find it pretty hard trade-off.

Is there a technical reason behind it? I guess the argument could be that out-of-line needs private info that `A` contains `B`, though I am not sure it that's it. Seems unconvincing vs drawbacks.

*Notes: I am not interested in reorganizing class hierarchy to avoid the problem.  The question is not purely academic; I had had `operator<<(ostream&, const B&)` and wanted to move definition out of the header.*

Comment: The class definition `A::B` is private to class `A`.  Make it public and it compiles live: https://godbolt.org/z/_FgdYt

Comment: @RichardCritten: He knows that. He doesn't want to make it public.

Comment: @NicolBolas Without class `A::B` being public how can it be used in the global (outside the scope of A) context?

Comment: @RichardCritten: That is *literally* the question he is asking. Or more specifically, why it isn't possible to do that.

Comment: you need to know there is `B` inside `A`, and private type is not visible to others AFAIK. if you do not want `B` in header, something like `PIMPL` may be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Accessibility in C++ is centered around the ability to access a name from a given scope. `A::B` names a private member of `A`. This means that declarations/definitions which are not either members of `A` or direct friends of `A` are not allowed to use the name `A::B` directly.

`f2` uses the name `A::B` in its declaration. If that declaration appears outside of the scope of `A::B`, it therefore must either be a member of `A` or a direct friend of `A`.

That's just how accessibility works in C++. What you're encountering is simply the inevitable result of how those rules play out.

What you're getting confused by is the oddball consequence of the rules for inline `friend` definitions. It's *they* who have the unexpected rules; or rather, unexpected interaction with obvious rules. These `friend` declarations are in a scope where `A::B` is already accessible, so they can use the name as much as they like. And since you can provide a definition for such functions in-situ, there is no need to make `A::B` visible to that definition.

Would it be theoretically possible to change the rules of accessibility, so as to automatically make external definitions of `friend`ed functions work *as if* they were defined in the class that `friend`ed them? That would be a very weird thing, since a function can be `friend`s of multiple classes. So which class would it work "as if" it had been defined within?

Comment: I would suspect language to allow accessing private name in `A` if the function is a friend of the name, not introduce "as-if" rules, so make A::B visible to friends of B, even if it's private. Friend could access privates of all the classes that friend it. I agree that this would an exception to standard access rule, but a warranted one IMHO. Current rules render friends of private nested classes useless unless defined inline. The relaxation is pretty slight but maybe it would have some non-obvious consequences. Surely friending the outside class for inner-related function seems bad.

Comment: @luk32: "*I would suspect language to allow accessing private name in A if the function is a friend of the name*" But that's the thing: there's no such thing as being "a friend of the name". Being a friend of a *class* means having access to *that class's* privates. The fact that that class just so happens to be a private member of something else is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Something like forward declaration or PIMPL can solve it.

---

```
//header
class A
{
    public:
    class B;
};

extern A::B instance;
void f2(const A::B&);

//main
int main(){
    f2(instance);
}

//impl / another header
class A::B{
friend void f1(const B&){};
friend void f2(const B&);
int data=0;
};

// impl
#include<iostream>
void f2(const A::B& b){
    std::cout << "inside:" << b.data;
}

A::B instance;
```

---

this should not be much different from make `A::B` private.

Comment: You made `B` public. The point was to avoid breaking encapsulation. This also means that `A` cannot store a member of type `B` or use it in any way that requires that a definition of the class exist.

Comment: @NicolBolas this is effectively private. that's said, if it is truly private, no global function can access it.

Comment: @NicolBolas you can use in the sense of `PIMPL`.

Comment: Global functions can if they're `friend` declared inline within `B`. Which is again the point of the question: why can you do it when it's inline defined, but not when it's externally defined.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think the point is *Is there a way to avoid friend repetition other than defining the function inline*. and my answer is on that point. BTW, this does not break encapsulation much AFAICT.

Comment: @NicolBolas and nothing outside `A` would have any type of instance to `B`. what's the point to make it global function after all?

Comment: As the OP said: `operator<<(ostream&, const B&)`.

Comment: @NicolBolas one can only possible to use this operator inside `A` (and `B`).

Comment: @appleapple Operator in `A` uses operator in `B`. Imagine that you have a `Tree` class and it has an internal private class implementing `Node` and you want to write a serializer for `Tree`.

Comment: @luk32 I see no problem.